# React Native Unhandled promise rejection | React-Native, Async,

Tags: javascript, react-native, asynchronous, async-await, fetch

I keep getting an Unhandled Promise Rejection
I'm Running React-Native with the EXPO CLI and am using React Hook Forms

Things I've tried and nothing has changed:

1. Gave my api (NodeJS) an SSL (I know ios wants one)
2. Refactored to regular  and react hooks for each field
3. Changed the BaseUrl to 10.0.2.2 AND THEN TRIED my personal IP address.
4. Changed to normal Promise AND THEN TRIED Axios calls

The console log just inside the `onSubmit` function returns the data from the form, but it stops there.

**The Full Error:**

> [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: (0, _auth.loginUser) is not a function. (In '(0, _auth.loginUser)(data)', '(0, _auth.loginUser)' is undefined)]
> at node_modules/react-hook-form/dist/index.cjs.development.js:1204:67 in 
> at [native code]:null in flushedQueue
> at [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue

**Login Component Code:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native';

import Input from '../Input';
import Button from '../Button';
import Link from '../Link';
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import { loginUser } from '../../helpers/data/auth';

const EMAIL_REGEX = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

export default function Login() {
  const { control, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    console.log(data)
    let response = await loginUser(data)
    if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
      console.log(response)
    } else {
      error
    }
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>

      <Controller
        control={control}
        name="email"
        defaultValue=''
        rules={{
          required: {value: true, message: 'Email is required' },
          pattern: {
            value: EMAIL_REGEX,
            message: 'Not a valid email'
          }
        }}
        render={({ onChange, onBlur, value }) => (
        <Input
          error={errors.email}
          errorText={errors?.email?.message}
          onBlur={onBlur}
          onChangeText={value => onChange(value)}
          value={value}
          placeholder={'Email'}
          textAlign={'center'}
        />
        )}
      />

      <Controller
        control={control}
        name="password"
        defaultValue=''
        rules={{ required: {value: true, message: 'Password is required' } }}
        render={({ onChange, onBlur, value }) => (
          <Input
            error={errors.password}
            errorText={errors?.password?.message}
            onBlur={onBlur}
            onChangeText={value => onChange(value)}
            value={value}
            secureTextEntry={true}
            placeholder={'Password'}
            textAlign={'center'}
          />
        )}
      />
      <Button onPress={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} label="LOGIN"/>

      <View style={styles.row}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Forgot your login details? </Text>
        <Link onPress={() => {}} label='Get help signing in.'/>
      </View>

    </View>
  )
}
```

**loginUser Fetch Call:**

```
import { baseUrl } from '../apiKeys.json';

const loginUser = async (data) => {
  const response = await fetch(`${baseUrl}/auth/signin`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  });
  return response.json();
}

export default { loginUser };
```

Save me...

Comment: **UPDATE** after adding the Method I get:

`Network request failed
at node_modules/whatwg-fetch/dist/fetch.umd.js:535:17 in setTimeout$argument_0
at [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue`


All errors I've receive have this `callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue`. Does anyone know what this does?

Answer (score 0):

Add the `export` infront of `const`

```
import { baseUrl } from '../apiKeys.json'; //not quite remember whether u can do this.

//add the export here.

export const loginUser = async (data) => {
  const response = await fetch(`${baseUrl}/auth/signin`, {
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  });
  return response.json();
}
```

Comment: I've tried before; both exporting all functions in an object and directly at the beginning of the function to no avail. I've also realized that I failed to annotate the `method: 'POST'`, but now I'm just getting a:
`Network request failed
at node_modules/whatwg-fetch/dist/fetch.umd.js:535:17 in setTimeout$argument_0
at [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue`

Comment: what is your backend?

Comment: NodeJs. I'm connecting to it with postman.

Comment: so it's now a nodejs problem, nothing related to your question right?

Comment: I don't believe so, because I can make successful calls via postman and even directly in the browser to the api.

Answer (score 0):

`Unhandled promise rejection` means that your code doesn't handle if there's an error occurring. In your `function`, use `trycatch` statement. Any error occurring will be handled by `catch`